# Docker Access Denied for user 'root'@'172.28.1.5' (using Password: NO)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run a local test environment for a rails web application. I have this setup running on another computer, but am running into a problem on a different one.

Here's the docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
 railsdev:
  build: ./
  image: railsdev
  depends_on:
    - db
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  networks:
    testing_net:
      ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5
  volumes:
      - /c/Users/my_user/Documents/directory:/mount_dir

 db:
   build: ./mysql
   image: mysqldev
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_DATABASE: db
   networks:
     testing_net:
       ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3

networks:
 testing_net:
     ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

I changed some of these values for privacy sake.

And here is my mysql DockerFile:

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=db
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_HOST=localhost
ENV MYSQL_PORT=3306
ENV MYSQL_USER=user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
COPY transfer.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

And finally my rails DockerFile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
WORKDIR ./
ENV DATABASE_URL=mysql2://172.28.1.3
ENV RAILS_ENV=development
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "-c", "cd mount_dir;bundle exec rake db:migrate;bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p8080"]
```

Typically, I run docker-compose up --build to build and start up these containers, and everything connects properly. I have the rails DockerFile set up to migrate the database, and the volume mounts properly. However, I'm getting the Access Denied for 'root'@'172.28.1.5' error. Typically this means the root password is incorrect, but I have verified that it is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

chances are that mysql user - root only allows 127.0.0.1 - and you didn't create root for 172.28.1.5.

Comment: how to do that considering you're not allowed to run mysql commands in the container without the root password?